# Given a projection, determine if it is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a projection onto the yz-plane. Is $T$ linear? If so, find a matrix $A$ so that $T = T_A$.

1st question I have: Does it matter that $T$ is projected on the yz plane? What would happen if it was the xy plane instead?

Anyways,  I came up with the following counter example:

let $T(x) = [xy, x+y, x+z]^{\textbf{T}}$

Then $T$ is not a linear transformation because it fails the second  property that defines a linear transformation $T(cX) = cT(X)$. I found that the first entry on output matrix are unequal. I got c<sup>2</sup>xy != cxy

Does my logic seem right?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define a projection?

Comment: “Projection” means something very specific. You can’t take any old map that has the $y$-$z$ plane as its image and claim it as a counterexample. Moreover, for your map $T(1,1,0)^T=(1,2,1)^T$, which doesn’t lie on the $y$-$z$ plane.

Comment: @amd so what does it mean to lie on the yz plane? Does that mean T(x) = (0, y, z)^(T)?

Comment: It means that the first coordinate of the point is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is the projection onto the $xy$-plane then $T(x,y,z)=(x,y,0)$.  One can check that $T$ is linear.  Applying $T$ to any basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ yields a matrix representation for $T$

Comment: So I can do the same thing for yz plane (as in the question) and just show that T is linear by proving the 2 properties?

Comment: There is an infinite number of linear projections onto the $$-$$ plane. Nothing in the problem statement says that the projection being discussed is orthogonal. Indeed, it says, verbatim, “**a** projection,” which opens up the possibility of other types of projections, e.g., $T: (x,y,z)^T\mapsto(0,y-x,z)^T$.